# Using Count and OR giving too high a value

Tags: sql, count, sybase

Hi I have a query that i want to return one value. If i run the query in two parts and add them together it is fine but when i try and the OR operator the value greatly increases.

Here is the first query:

```
    select count (*) from tablename where DATE_TRE='2013-10-06' and SECTOR= '1'
```

This returns 3867

Here is the second:

```
 select count (*) from tablename where DATE_TRE='2013-10-06' and SECTOR= '01'
```

This returns 9

When i run it using a Or like this

```
 select count (*) from tablename where DATE_TRE='2013-10-06' and SECTOR= '1' OR SECTOR = '01'
```

I get the value of 4066, anyone any ideas im wanting the figure of 3876

Comment: as the first answer points out `AND` has higher priority in binding than `OR` your last `WHERE` is therefore equivalent to `(DATE_TRE='2013-10-06' and SECTOR= '1') OR SECTOR = '01'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it because it evaluates it like this

```
select count (*) 
from tablename 
where (DATE_TRE='2013-10-06' and SECTOR= '1') OR SECTOR = '01'
```

When you are looking for this(Try this one)

```
select count (*) 
from tablename 
where DATE_TRE='2013-10-06' and (SECTOR= '1' OR SECTOR = '01')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked fine and i will accept it when i can.

Answer (score 2):

`and` binds stronger than `or`. use parentheses

```
select count (*) 
from tablename 
where DATE_TRE = '2013-10-06' 
and (SECTOR= '1' OR SECTOR = '01')
```

or

```
select count (*) 
from tablename 
where DATE_TRE = '2013-10-06' 
and SECTOR in ('1', '01')
```

Comment: Yes it is everywhere the same.

Answer (score 1):

put some braces arround SECTOR= '1' OR SECTOR = '01':

```
select count (*) from tablename where DATE_TRE='2013-10-06' 
and ( SECTOR= '1' OR SECTOR = '01')
```